# Why doing array[array%10] on a 2-D numpy array returns a 3-D array?

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a 2-D array made using

```py
array = numpy.arange(1, 101).reshape(10,10)
```

and when I do something like `array[array>0]` I get a 1-D array, but when I do `array[array%10]` I get a 3-D array. I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: This is related to [numpy's advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

Comment: To use a % as a mask, you need to first convert it to a boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what you were expecting that to do.  In a command line, you should type `array > 0` and see what you get.  That's an array of booleans.  When you do indexing with an array of booleans, that selects certain elements from the array, on a matching basis.  In that case, every element was true, so you get all 100 elements.

But `array%10` returns a 2D array of numbers.  Numpy interprets those as the indices of the rows you want.  The first row of `array%10` is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0].  So, numpy builds you a plane containing those rows of the array.  The second row happens to be the same, so you end up with ten identical 10x10 planes selected from the original array.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wasn't really expecting anything tbh. I just did it out of curiosity since I've just started to learn pandas and numpy.